# Grunt Error - Warning: Task "bower-install" not found

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, bower

I've just tried to run `Angular-bootstrap` generator and answer all the options as so:

```
[?] What version of angular would you like to use? 1.2.15
[?] Which official angular modules would you need? animate, route
[?] Any third-party component you may require? bootstrap#~3.1.0
[?] Would you want me to support old versions of Internet Explorer (eg. before IE9)? nose arrow keys)
[?] Should I set up one of those JS preprocessors for you? none
[?] Should I set up one of those CSS preprocessors for you? sass
[?] What's the base name of your project? bootstrap
[?] Under which lincense your project shall be released? MIT
[?] Would you mind telling me your username on GitHub? mgcrea
```

Everything runs fine and dandy, but when I try and run grunt serve or grunt build I get the following error: `Warning: Task "bower-install" not found. Use --force to continue.`

I've tried to run bower install & npm install to fix this error but I get the following: n`pm WARN package.json bootstrap@0.1.0 No README data`

Has anyone any advice on how I can resolve this?

Comment: To overcome this I've just manually added the module after running the angular generator

Comment: you should really post the answer as an "answer" not a "comment"

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it was just a workaround he used to continue his own work... and that workaround does not answer the question

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following:

1. try with "bowerInstall" - not "bower-install" as this option has been renamed in later versions
   (see https://github.com/mgcrea/generator-angular-bootstrap/issues/2)
2. Make sure you run bowerInstall from the root directory of your app
3. have a look at your Gruntfile.js - is there a function "bowerInstall" ? If not, just add it:

   ```
   bowerInstall: {
       target: {

           // Point to the files that should be updated when
           // you run `grunt bower-install`
           src: [
               'app/views/**/*.html',   // .html support...
               'app/*.html',   // .html support...
           ],

           // Optional:
           // ---------
           cwd: '',
           dependencies: true,
           devDependencies: false,
           exclude: [],
           fileTypes: {},
           ignorePath: '',
           overrides: {}
       }
   }
   ```

   You can add this function for example right after the function filerev: {....}
4. Make sure you have installed the package "grunt-bower-install". Have a look into your package.json. You should find the following line there:

   > "grunt-bower-install": "^1.6.0",

   If not, just add it and then run:

   > npm install
   >
   > grunt

Comment: Running the "npm install" command locally before executing grunt was the missing step for me.